# What does it mean that "the constants true and false can represented with only nand"?

Tags: logic

Does this statement mean that you can represent true and false **without using AND or OR**?

I figured out that $ \lnot A\,\text{nand}\, A = \text{true}$

But how can I represent $ \text{false} $ without using AND or OR... or does the question not imply this restriction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(A \mid A)$ is the same as $\neg A$, so to get "false", just do $\top \mid \top \iff ( ( A \mid A ) \mid A ) \mid ( ( A \mid A ) \mid A )$

Comment: What is the | symbol?

Comment: Was an accident.  The $|$ symbol is our not-and symbol.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche MSE doesn't like duplicates, even of deleted answers.  I might hit the rep cap today, so it might not matter anyway, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**¬A** can be represented as **(A nand A)**.

So, basically swap **¬A** with **(A nand A)** ==> **(A nand A) nand A)** which will always be true.

Now, to represent false in only **nand** ==> you simply take the previous answer and add
at the beginning not.

**¬( (A nand A) nand A))**, since we know **nand** can only be **false** if both cases is **True** then we use the

[ **(A nand A) nand A)**] **nand** [ **(A nand A) nand A)**] = **false**

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

$(\lnot A\operatorname{nand}A)\operatorname{nand}(\lnot A\operatorname{nand}A)$

As each expression in the brackets will evaluate to true, the overall expression would be the negation after the and which would always be false.